# Original Array changes when its copy is changed in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, array

So i have a method in my javascript, **transformJson(input)** which is returning a JSON.

The result returned is being used in another method as below:

```
handleFinalJson(){
    this.originalVar = this.transformJson(input);
    console.log('orgVar:'+JSON.stringify(this.originalVar));
    //The console shows the JSON as of this format:[{..}]}].
    
    this.originalVarClone1 = [...this.originalVar];
    this.originalVarClone2 = [...this.originalVar];
}
```

Now i am sending the *originalVarClone1* to child LWC where post some more operations I am finally using it on my UI.

Also, in my parent LWC i am executing some more logic in a different method as below:

```
handleAnotherMethod(){
    if(some condition){
        let backupClone1Data = [...this.originalVarClone1];
        /*
        .
        executing some logic
        .
        .
        */      
    }else{
        let backupClone2Data = [...this.originalVarClone2];
    }
}
```

But whenever there is a change in data of *originalVarClone1* my *originalVarClone2* also gets changed.

I did some research and found that the spread only makes a shallow copy and it would be better if i could do a deep copy.
So I thought of implementing the deep copy for *originalVarClone1*
using below two approaches:

```
this.originalVarClone1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalVar);
```

and

```
this.originalVarClone1 = this.originalVar.map(object => ({...object}));
```

but it didn't help.

Assuming that my understanding of the issue is correct, how do i fix this issue?

Comment: How does JSON input looks like?

Comment: Hi Raul, i have updated my question with more details.

Comment: The other options should work fine, you may want to post a minimal code illustrating the problem for us to help better.

Comment: Hi Raul, You were right. Had to make a small change . Posting the working solution below for future references.

Answer (score 0):

So, initially i thought that making a deep copy for *originalVarClone1* would fix the issue but turns out I had to make changes for *originalVarClone2* also.

```
handleFinalJson(){
    this.originalVar = this.transformJson(input);
    console.log('orgVar:'+JSON.stringify(this.originalVar));
    //The console shows the JSON as of this format:[{..}]}].
    
    /*this.originalVarClone1 = [...this.originalVar];
    this.originalVarClone2 = [...this.originalVar];*/
    this.originalVarClone1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalVar);
    this.originalVarClone2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalVar);

}
```

The above change fixed the issue of *originalVarClone2* getting changed when there was a change in *originalVarClone1*